# Flutter loop through object (Basics)

Tags: arrays, flutter, object, each

Would like to loop through a multidimensional object but appear to be missing something.

```
String label, action;
    var symbol;
    Object toggles = [
      {
        label = 'Reckless',
      },
      {
        label = 'Feckless',
      },
      {
        label = 'Legless',
      },
    ];
```

I attempted to use this in a Row:

```
   Row(
       children: for (var toggle in toggles) {
Text('label ${toggle.label}')
                  },
                );
```

Error message concerns `for` stating that it expected an identified. Clearly I'm not fully understanding how to do this.

Comment: If my question is so awful then perhaps you could explain why and then I wouldn't do it again.

Comment: can't you use a Map or List rather than object?

Comment: @rosh-dev I have tried with Map but it states that I cannot used named values. I believe I'm missing something in the object construction.

Comment: you can create object array by changing syntax like 'label' : 'Reckless' but you can't iterate through toggles array because it doesn't implement Iterable<dynamic> class. I think you need to find a another solution for your requirement

Comment: @rosh-dev Thanks. Ultimately I want to control the entire object for this via JSON as I'll also be dealing with language variants. If we were to imagine that "toggles" was in fact a JSON array containing the values of label, symbol and action per record, would that be a better approach?

Comment: did you try json.decode dart function? easy generate Map from your json

Comment: I'm experimenting with it now. Given what I want to do later this looks like a better choice anyway. Thanks for your help, R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run your code. The error :

```
Error: The type 'Object' used in the 'for' loop must implement 'Iterable<dynamic>'.
```

You cannot iterate on an `Object`.

If you change `Object toggles =` to `List toggles =` for example (which is iteratable), then, it is working.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds very plausible. Ultimately I want to use JSON for these objects so I'm looking at the JSON functions in Dart but this is extremely helpful for my understanding.